# nasm: fatal: unable to open input file (but file exist ?)

Tags: nasm, dosbox

Okay so i tried to open two file , first file called test.asm that i created using

```
echo mov ax,5 > test.asm
```

Then i have another file called sambungstring.asm that i created manually

I tried to compile the file using this command

```
nasm <filename>.asm -o <filename>.com
```

I can compile test.asm but why does sambungstring.asm gives error ?!?! they're located at exact same location

[image]

As can be seen in the image , test.asm compiled successfully and test.com appeared in the directory , but sambungstring.asm gives error.

Please help me , i've already spent 3 days trying to install nasm and running it in dosbox , this is the first time i finally able to run nasm in dosbox .

Comment: Does DOSBox have Long Filename support? Otherwise you'll have to use the [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Comment: i've renamed the sambungstring.asm to all uppercase (SAMBUNGSTRING.asm) but still not work

Comment: @Michael thanks , i tried creating a dummy "SambungString.asm" using echo > sambungstring.asm , out of my expectation , the file that appear in the direction was sambungs.asm , it looks like filename length is limited to 8 character , thanks it works now

Comment: yes it looks like i have to use the 8.3 filename